# Custom Taxonomy Template file not being used

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I know there are countless questions on here about this, but all of them suggest the same thing I'm already trying to do, but I appear to be missing/misunderstanding something here.

I'm creating an FAQs section for a site, and have the following:

- `faq` custom post type
- `faqs` custom taxonomy for categorisation of FAQ pages

Both are updated to their most recent versions as of time of writing.

My goal is to have a page that lists all of those FAQ categories, which I can then click, to reveal all of the FAQ pages associated with the FAQ category.

I have created the file `archive-faq.php` to try and list the FAQ pages themselves, but the file is not being used.

I have also created the file `taxonomy-faqs.php`, to list the different categories in the taxonomy, but the file is not being used.

I'm using the [Custom Post Type UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) plugin to manage the creation of custom post types and taxonomies, since I have a few of them now.

And I have indeed tried refreshing permalinks, several times.

Just in case this is relevant, I'm using the [Advanced Custom Fields PRO](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin to manage the creation of various fields (since this site is comprised entirely of bespoke pages, no blog).

And also, in case this is relevant, I do have a piece of code allowing me to remove the name of the custom post type from the URL to the page:

```
function remove_slug($post_link, $post) {
    if(!in_array($post->post_type, ['availability_page']) || 'publish' != $post->post_status) {
        return $post_link;
    }

    $post_link = str_replace('/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link);

    return $post_link;
}

add_filter('post_type_link', 'remove_slug', 10, 3);

function parse_request($query) {
    if(!$query->is_main_query() || 2 != count($query->query) || !isset($query->query['page'])) {
        return;
    }

    if(!empty( $query->query['name'])) {
        $query->set('post_type', array('post', 'availability_page', 'page'));
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'parse_request');
```

I'm not hugely adept with WordPress, but the client was insistent we use WordPress for their site. And since I'm so used to ProcessWire (which I believe is a far more practical solution for entirely bespoke websites), I'm finding it a bit difficult to adjust to the very fixed nature of WordPress.

So, any pointers as to why the template files I created are not being used would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've identified the error of my ways, it was down to a misconfiguration and a misunderstanding.

Firstly, the `archive-{post-type}.php` file was not being loaded because the 'Has Archive' option for the custom post type was set to `false`. It worked the second I flipped that.

Secondly, I was under the impression that the `taxonomy-{taxonomy-name}.php` file was used to list the terms under the taxonomy, that is not correct. That is specifically for using a custom template for a post under that taxonomy.

It usually always is something simple. If only I'd just waited a bit longer before asking the question. Though sometimes, trying to work it out while you already have a question on SE seems to spur me further to work it out before someone else does!